# Is HttpClient flawed when sending large files/content?

Tags: c#, .net-4.5

After reading/googling about HttpClient, I have the impression that this component is not suitable for uploading large files or contents to REST services.

1. It seems that if the upload takes more than the established timeout, the transmission will fail. Does it make sense? What does this timeout means?
2. Getting progress information seems hard or requires add-ons.

So my questions are: Is it possible to sove these two issues without too much hassle? Otherwise, what's the best approach when working with large contents and REST services?

Comment: Can't we have a rest endpoint that can get stream instead of a large file.

Comment: There is a request timeout which will abort the request if its reached which is possible if you're sending a large file.  You may be better off with HttpWebRequest where you can set the timeout.

Comment: @Andy, you can also set the timeout with HttpClient; but to what value should you set it to? You don't know it advance how long it will take to upload the file... I have written [an article](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2014/01/14/tackling-timeout-issues-when-uploading-large-files-with-httpwebrequest/) about this issue when using `HttpWebRequest`, but unfortunately the solution I found doesn't apply to `HttpClient`.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque If you're allowing large uploads then a very high / disabled timeout is pretty much your own option.  The only way I saw to increase the timeout for HttpClient affected all connections in the application, whereas you can set the timeout on HttpWebRequest for each instance.

Comment: @Andy, I don't get it; what about [HttpClient.Timeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.timeout.aspx)? Anyway, using an very large or infinite timeout is not a good option, as I explained in my article.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque hmm, I must have been looking at the wrong documentation.

Comment: Tried using @ThomasLevesque solution but get warning that WebRequest is now obsolete in .Net 6 and to use HttpClient instead.

Comment: @karmelcorn yes, HttpWebRequest is obsolete. I have a solution for HttpClient [here](https://thomaslevesque.com/2018/02/25/better-timeout-handling-with-httpclient/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes, if the upload takes longer that the TimeOut, the upload will fail. This is a limitation of `HttpClient`. The most robust solution to this problem is the one that [Thomas Levesque](https://stackoverflow.com/users/98713/thomas-levesque) has [written an article about](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2014/01/14/tackling-timeout-issues-when-uploading-large-files-with-httpwebrequest/), and linked in his comments to your question. You have to use `HttpWebRequest` instead of `HttpClient`.
2. If you want to get progress messages, open the file as a `FileStream` and manually iterate through it, copying bytes in increments onto the (upload) request stream. As you go, you can calculate your progress relative to the file size.

TL's code example. [Be sure to read the article though!](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2014/01/14/tackling-timeout-issues-when-uploading-large-files-with-httpwebrequest/):

```
long UploadFile(string path, string url, string contentType)
{
    // Build request
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
    request.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;
    request.ContentType = contentType;
    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(path);
    request.Headers["Content-Disposition"] = string.Format("attachment; filename=\"{0}\"", fileName);

    try
    {
        // Open source file
        using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(path))
        {
            // Set content length based on source file length
            request.ContentLength = fileStream.Length;

            // Get the request stream with the default timeout
            using (var requestStream = request.GetRequestStreamWithTimeout())
            {
                // Upload the file with no timeout
                fileStream.CopyTo(requestStream);
            }
        }

        // Get response with the default timeout, and parse the response body
        using (var response = request.GetResponseWithTimeout())
        using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
        {
            string json = reader.ReadToEnd();
            var j = JObject.Parse(json);
            return j.Value<long>("Id");
        }
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        if (ex.Status == WebExceptionStatus.Timeout)
        {
            LogError(ex, "Timeout while uploading '{0}'", fileName);
        }
        else
        {
            LogError(ex, "Error while uploading '{0}'", fileName);
        }
        throw;
    }
}
```